# EC2 micro instance randomly uses 100% of CPU and stays there

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, node.js

I am running a node.js service and a docker postgres image on an EC2 micro instance. Usually it runs fine for weeks / months but randomly the instance goes up to 100% CPU usage and stays there, completely hogging the instance. No SSH is possible, no reboot. I have to kill it and start it again.

Network traffic is low at that time, so I suspect it's not a Bot DoSing the server.

The node.js server runs on PM2 with a memory limit of 500MB. The server has 1GB RAM. It may be out of memory and swapping hogs the CPU. I'm not sure what could cause 1GB of RAM being used all of a sudden. The node.js server is usually around 100MB a leak should be prevented by PM2's restart.

[image]

I have no idea how to debug this, I can't find anything in the syslog (but I don't know what I'd be looking for)

Comment: How much swap does this instance have?

Comment: @AlexD Turns out it didn't have a swapfile, I added a 1GB swap file no. Could that have been the cause for CPU usage?

Comment: A large swap file would cause swap thrashing and unresponsive system when memory is exhausted.